# how to use Membership.ValidateUser using entities connection to DB?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i have a web service call a method to authenticate user

the method is :

```
public bool getUser(string User, string Pass)
{
    return( Membership.ValidateUser(TvId, TvPass));
}
```

but Membership.ValidateUser need to get connection to db, and I'm using Entity framework , any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have two different connection strings defined, one for EF and one for the Membership provider, even though they're both the same DB.

So in the Web.config we have:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <!-- Used by the EF DbContext -->
        <add name="EFConnection" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Persist Security Info=False;Trusted_Connection=yes;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
        <!-- Used for membership, see the Web.config entries below -->
        <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=localhost;initial catalog=MyDB;Persist Security Info=False;Trusted_Connection=yes;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <membership>
            <providers>
                <!-- Uses the ApplicationServices connection string defined above to set the connection information for the membership provider -->
                <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="ePubDirect" />
            </providers>
        </membership>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

There's a load of other stuff in the Web.config too of course, and your connection strings will likely be very different than my local dev environment, but this is the type of wiring you need for your Membership to just work.

Instead of System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider you may need something more like:

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Or whatever membership provider you're using. Your detailed settings are likely to be different to these too.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't mean you r using entity framework or Ado.net classes to make the connection with the database. membership provider will work with entity framework as well. you need to define the membership connection string in the Web.config file